# HttpUrlConnection headers response code is 403

Tags: java, android, http-headers, authorization, httpurlconnection

The response http code of the given snippet at the end of this post is 403. 403 means forbidded. But i am accessing and posting into it through google chrome POSTman app. I am unable to resolve the problem in this case. I have tried many other solutions like:

httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Basic "+Header);

httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("ApiKey","abcd1234");

```
  HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL ("http:abc.com")).openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization",Header);
          //  Header = "ApiKey:abcd1234" ;
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
```

Comment: See **Retrofit** (http://square.github.io/retrofit/) library to do HTTP stuff easily in Android programming. It saves a lot of time.

Comment: does the working request submitted through Postman appear on the "network" tab of Chrome dev tools?  from there, you should be able to see the structure of the working request (and either figure out the expected structure from there, or post back here w/ those additional details)

Comment: yeah but i don't have much time for it now. I ll do work with retrofit in future.

Answer (score 0):

BASIC authentication data needs to be baase64 encoded, something like

```
String encoded = Base64.encode(username+":"+password); connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+encoded);
```

Comment: Well....in my case.....instead of BASIC.....NO Authorization type will work. how should i write it then?

Comment: well, as suggested by jamey Graham, inspecting the postman request and the api request can help to solve the problem.

Comment: How can i inspect that? Chrome network tool isn't giving anything